# High IIS CPU Usage, but only on a single processor

Tags: iis-6

I am monitoring a server that has multiple processors.

According to task manager, one processor has been hovering around 95% consistently (not dropping below 90% at all) for about 15 minutes. All other processors are showing an average of 1% load.

Is there a misconfiguration that is only allowing IIS to use one processor? Could there be some rogue request that won't end? If so, why hasn't the request timed out?

This is Windows Server 2003.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which process in the Task Manager list is using all the processor time?

Comment: w3wp only.

It's staying at 16% consistently (6 processor server).

Comment: Is the website a busy one? It would not be unusual for a web server to show 16% usage if it is steadily answering requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you broken up your applications into multiple app pools?  It is entirely possible that it is one of the worker processes(associated with one specific application) that is consuming all of the resources.

As i recall Windows 2003 comes with IIS 6.0.

IIS shouldn't be using one processor, and each visitor gets a unique thread.  So if it's all distributed on one processor it is likely that one user, or application is using all of your resources.

As a rule of thumb breaking up processes into multiple pools is best.  It allows for better use of the additional processors, and in the event that one application bails, it does not harm other areas or sites.

Comment: If the issue is with the w3wp.exe process this is your application, and not IIS.